# wordpress create new menu option in admin for list woocommerce category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create new menu option in admin, for list woocommerce categories. (something like wordpress post list).

[image: example image]

Comment: You need to create custom post type (function: register_post_type) in your themes function.php to enable custom admin menu

Comment: that will create new post type, I want from the existing (woocommerce product category). If you have example for list woocommerce category, please share with me.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170613/woocommerce-cpt

Comment: not really helpful, I only have have option to code custom to list category. But this will take extra time instead of default.

Comment: I think you need to add in custom after creating the custom posttype and code to list from woocommerce.

Comment: I really don't know how to do with register new post type and work with woocommerce category with all default functionality that wordpress provide.